# HDMI Audio Drivers not found on Intel 10i7 NUC running Ubuntu 22.04.03LTS

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04, hdmi, intel

this is another one of those Ubuntu/no audio out via HDMI. I'm a bit of a Ubuntu novice so bear with me.

I haven't seen a similar posted for a while, and I'm wondering if anyone has any better fixes/work arounds than everything I've seen before about this problem over the past few years.

I have an Intel 10i7 NUC that up until a week ago was running Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, and was hooked up via HDMI to the same TV and was able to play sound.

As I was upgrading the SSD, I installed Ubuntu instead of reinstalling Lubuntu, and while everything else works, there is no sound via the HDMI and Ubuntu only reports a dummy sound driver.

If I use the headphone jack output on the computer and a pair of speakers, I get sound.  Ubuntu detects the plug and asks if I'm using a headset or headphones.

I'm pretty sure from what I've been able to figure out via lots of Google searches is that there's some sort of audio drivers conflict, where for some reason Ubuntu can't install the drivers needed for this Intel chipset to push audio out via HDMI, or gets confused.

I've tried all the tricks and tweaks I've found on the internet to no luck.

1. I've changed `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_iommu=igfx_off"`, restarted grub, and rebooted.
2. messed with pipewire and pulse audio settings as well as alsa, killing processes, restarting, making sure everything was updated, force reloading, etc. etc.
3. Found some information about a midi daemon that someone `sudo apt purge` and fixed it for them, but I didn't have this midi daemon installed.

`aplay -l` reports `no soundcards found`

`inxi -i` reports:
`CPU: 6-core Intel Core i7-10710U (-MT MCP-) speed/min/max: 1310/400/4700 MHz Kernel: 6.2.0-39-generic x86_64 Up: 7h 5m Mem: 2812.6/64007.4 MiB (4.4%) Storage: 3.64 TiB (65.4% used) Procs: 400 Shell: Bash 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13`

Where do I go from here?  Should I start disabling things to see if there's a conflict somewhere? Is there just some sort of generic driver I can install that will put sound out through the HDMI?

I honestly *don't* need to fix this problem, since I have a work around with the headphone jack and external speakers, but it is annoying...

thanks.

Comment: I solved this -- the hard way.  I wiped the computer and reloaded everything, but when I loaded Ubuntu onto the computer from an external USB drive, I made sure to have a pair of headphones plugged into the output jack of my monitor.  That was enough for Ubuntu to "find" that I had audio that needed to be setup via HDMI.  Annoying, but it is a fix, since I think without the audio out plugged into the HDMI output it may not always load the drivers.  Seems to be an intermittent Ubuntu bug...